# Store users´ token in React Redux or store them in cookies?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

i am programming a MERN webapp. I am storing Users´ tokens with React Redux so i retrieve this token to get users´ data, but gathering some info about refresh token to implement this feature, i realized that some examples store users´ session in cookies. My questions are, What is the best practice? is it okay to store tokens with React Redux? Please Help me to figure it out this.

Comment: If you want to persist a session, a Cookie should be fine. You can also look into localStorage/sessionStorage as well